# Передать данные из TextBox'ов в базу SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-localdb

На работе появилась необходимость передавать входные данные из TextBox'ов в базу данных SQL Server. Вот мои попытки реализовать это. Проблема в том что никаких ошибок не происходит но и БД пуста. Где я просчитался? 
Подскажите хотя бы простую запись в БД при событии кнопки. Дальше я сам смогу.
Буду благодарен за любую подсказку!

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"data source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;attachdbfilename=|datadirectory|\patientsdb.mdf;
        integrated security=true;multipleactiveresultsets=true;app=entityframework");

try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Pacients(NAME, AGE) VALUES ('wee','weeee')", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Соединение успешно");
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Во время соединения произошла ошибка" + ex);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: в какой именно БД пусто? Где конкретно вы проверяете наличие данных?

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись! После выполнения запроса я захожу в БД чтоб просмотреть данные но там пусто. Захожу проверить вручную запросом на SELECT * FROM Pacients. В БД patientsdb.mdf.

Comment: дайте я угадаю, эта БД у вас в папке проекта лежит, да? А ещё у вас есть папка Bin/Debug где лежит ваш exe файл, и вот в той папке тоже есть такая же бд, куда вы данные добавляете на самом деле, верно?

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы.

Comment: То есть вы нашли данные, что добавляли? Вам нужно пояснение почему так происходит?

Comment: Данные я не нашел. Я их не вижу. Я понимаю, что возможно идет попытка обращения к БД которая в папке проекта а вместо этого записывает в bin'e. Но как получить данные я не допер пока.

Comment: скорее всего, каждый раз, как вы звпускаете ваше приложение через студию, студия удаляет ту БД, что в папке bin/debug и копирует туда БД из проекта. Попробуйте запустить exe файл напрямую из bin/debug, выполнить добаление данных, и проверить сразу на месте были ли данные добавлены.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Данные увидел. Но как мне избежать такого поведения при запуске? Мне же не нужен такой хаос.

Comment: тут нет хаоса, юзеры же будут exe запускать, потому для юзеров ничего перезаписываться не будет. Если вам надо подключаться к конкретной БД, которая находится в конкретной папке, то указывайте абсолютный путь к БД в строке подключения вместо `|datadirectory|\patientsdb.mdf`

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли!

Comment: Пожалуйста (+ 5 символов)